# Replicate =LARGE and =SMALL function in Excel to Python

Tags: python

I would like to obtain the k-th largest/ k-th smallest value from numerical columns in a .xlsx file imported in Python. I have heard that a sorted array is required for the same.
So I tried isolating different columns into an array in Python using openpyxl like so

```
col_array = []
for i in range(1,1183):
  col_array = factor2_db.cell(row=i,column=2).value
  print(col_array)
```

And then used the function below to find the kth Largest value but that resulted in an error in Line 2
``

```
0 class Solution(object):
1 def findKthLargest(self,nums, k):
2 nums_sorted= sorted(nums) **TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable**
3 if k ==1:
4    return nums_sorted[-1]
5 temp = 1
6 return nums_sorted[len(nums_sorted)-k]
  
7 ob1 = Solution()
8 print(ob1.findKthLargest(col_array,5))
```

Comment: ``col_array `` is not really an array (or rather a ``list``), because instead of appending, you're assigning the last value of the iterated cell to the variable ``col_array`` when you write ``col_array = factor2_db...`` in your loop. For future reference, please include the **full** error stack in your question. Being able to see the line where the exception happens helps us immensely when we're on-the-fly-remote-debugging your code.

Comment: Not sure whey the excel tag - just because this is an import from excel - were you expecting a soln. being driven from that end of the source data (e.g. sorting values in excel before importing?

Comment: @JB-007 Yes, thank you  I tried importing the sorted value from excel itself but then the original database wasn't flexible enough to allow that hence I had to drop that approach

Answer (score 0):

**Soln**

Strictly speaking, your variable `col_array` is not a *multi-dimensional* array - it's simply a single value presented as a list that gets overwritten 1182 times (i.e. range(1,1183)).

I tried the following and had favourable results:

```
col_array=[]
for i in range(10): col_array.append(i)
print(col_array)
```

*you can customise the append using something (untested) like this:* `col_array.append( factor2_db.cell(row=i, column= 2).value)`

```
def kth(k, large=False):
    global col_array
    col_array.sort(key=None, reverse=large)
    print(f'col_array = {col_array}, col_array[{k}] = {col_array[k]}')
    return col_array[k-1]


print(kth(4, True))
```

Noting the first element of a list is indexed 0, although you wouldn't ordinarily talk of returning the '0th' smallest / largest element, whence the adjustment -1 in `return col_array[k-1]`

---

**Demonstration:**

[image: 4th smallest]

[image: 4th smallest]

**Additional notes:**

To preserve the original ordering, replicate col_array at outset - one way to achieve this:

```
col_array_copy = []; col_array_copy += (x for x in col_array)
```

Then proceed as above after replacing 'col_array' with 'col_array_copy'.